# Abrir File Excel PHP

Tags: php, excel

Estoy buscando la manera de abrir un archivo Excel a través de PHP, la intención es que a través de este movimiento se pueda detonar una macro al Open del File. No tengo nada desarrollado, pueden darme una idea de como hacerlo.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo para trabajar con los Excel en PHP he usado [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) y la verdad es que es una librería que me ha gustado bastante.

Es bastante sencilla de utilizar y hay bastante [documentación online](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Seguro que encuentras lo que buscas o al menos un punto de partida para empezar.

Espero te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: por lo general esperamos a ver que es lo que el usuario a intentado, y solo vemos problemas de programacion... no vemos sugerencias ya que tu respuesta no es una respuesta absoluta ... y puede probocar entrar en debates ...